# Javascript functions return lines of function code or "{[native code]}," what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, getselection

I am writing some code to find the user selection in a contenteditable div, I'm taking my code from [this quirksmode article](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_range.html).

```
function findSelection(){
  var userSelection;
  if (window.getSelection) {userSelection = window.getSelection;} 
   else if (document.selection){userSelection = document.selection.createRange();} // For microsoft
  if (userSelection.text){return userSelection.text} //for Microsoft
   else {return userSelection} 
  }
```

I'm testing it in Chrome and Firefox, if I do an `alert(userSelection)` within the function or an alert(findSelection();) outside the function, it returns `function getSelection() {[native code]}`. If I do `console.log(findSelection();)` it gives me `getSelection()`. Is there something I've done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to

if (window.getSelection) {userSelection = window.getSelection();}

(`getSelection`**`()`**)

Answer (score 3):

getSelection is a function... you need to execute it to get the selection?

```
if (window.getSelection) {userSelection = window.getSelection();}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is to get the text of the selection. Even with the typo fixed, you've got inconsistent behaviour: IE is returning the selection's text as a string while other browsers will return a `Selection` object that will give you the selection text string only when its `toString()` method is called.

The following would be better:

```
function getSelectionText(){
    if (window.getSelection) {
        return "" + window.getSelection();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        return document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
}
```